# My number guesser won't take the correct response. Therefore, asking non-stop

Tags: ruby

I am trying to piece a small method with no perimeters that generates a random number from 1 - 10, and if guessed incorrectly, prompts a "nope", and repetitively asks you to guess until you guess the correct number("Guess my number").

However, I've come across a problem, where even if the guess is a correct guess, it keeps saying, "nope" and asks the question, "guess my number" repetitively.

```
def random_number;
  state = false;
  answer = rand(10);

  until state == true;
    puts "Guess my number"
    guess = gets.chomp;
    if answer == guess;
      puts "nice"
      state = true;
    else
      puts "nope";
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to convert user input to integer

```
guess = gets.chomp.to_i
```

The issue is you are trying to compare `string` with `integer`. So if guess is `"5"` and answer is 5

```
answer == guess
#=> false
```

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing that out!